# How do I get a prompt box to send data to a chat box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**How do I get a prompt box to send data to a chat box?**

I've been trying to get my chat box to receive data from a prompt then a person's message, but if I do send a message it will say that person is undefined and then the person's message.

```css
/*Chat box*/

#chatbox {
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: table;
  padding: 10px 20px 12px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  height: 40.8em;
  width: 52em;
}


/*Chatbox inside border*/

.chatboxborder {
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px 20px 12px 15px;
  height: 2.8em;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 20em;
}


/*Chat message*/

#chatspace {
  transition-duration: 5s;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  right: 240px;
  left: 20px;
}

#chatbox p {
  transition-duration: 5s;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  background: #E6E6E6;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxtwo">
  <script>
    //Your username is asked when a user opens the window //
    window.addEventListener('load',
      function() {


        var person = prompt("Enter your username");
        if (person != null) {
          document.getElementById("username").innerHTML =
            "Welcome, " + person + ".";
          // If the prompt is empty, anoterh appears //
          while (person == "" || person == null) {
            person = prompt("Your username can't be empty!", "");
            document.getElementById("username").innerHTML =
              "Welcome, " + person + ".";
          }
        }
      }, false);
  </script>

  <p id="username"></p>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div id="chatbox">

    <div class="chatboxborder" id="chatboxborder">


    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="fixed" id="boxfive">
  <script>
    // The message is showed in the chatbox //
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#submitmsg').click(function() {

        var message = $('#usermsg').val();

        $('#chatboxborder').append('<p id="username">' + ' says: ' + message + '</p id="username">' + '<br>');
        $('#usermsg').val('');
      });
    });
  </script>
  <form name="message">
    <input style="width: 83%" name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" placeholder="Say something">
    <button type="button" id="submitmsg" value="Send">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet wouldn't run because you didn't include jQuery. I fixed that for you.

Comment: It's not affecting your code, but have an invalid `</p id="username">` tag. You can't put attributes inside a closing HTML tag; it should just be `</p>`.

Comment: Your example code doesn't show the `undefined` username because your `append()` is missing something, but I assume you had `$('#chatboxborder').append('<p id="username">' + person + ' says: ' + ...` at some point. [@Scath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49429905/574531) shows a working solution, but in case it wasn't clear, your problem was with the variable scope; you defined `person` as a local variable in the event listener callback so it couldn't be used anywhere else.

Comment: See, what I thought was that person was the ID of the prompt. That's why I thought I could get my chat box to read the input by having an element on the page that already read the input. Also, thank you for fixing the jQuery issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add some explanation as to why this fixes the problem, the original code was storing the user's name in a local variable inside the event listener callback. Trying to use that variable outside the callback scope would result in undefined because it didn't exist there.
You can just store the persons name in a global variable and use it when they send a message. Example in the snippet.

```js
//Your username is asked when a user opens the window //
var name 
window.addEventListener('load',
  function() {
  var person = prompt("Enter your username");
    if (person != null) {
      document.getElementById("username").innerHTML =
        "Welcome, " + person + ".";
        name = person        
      // If the prompt is empty, anoterh appears //
      while (person == "" || person == null) {
        person = prompt("Your username can't be empty!", "");
        document.getElementById("username").innerHTML =
          "Welcome, " + person + ".";
      }
    }
  }, false);

// The message is showed in the chatbox //
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submitmsg').click(function() {
    var message = $('#usermsg').val();
    $('#chatboxborder').append('<p id="username">' + name + ' says: ' + message + '</p>' + '<br>');
    $('#usermsg').val('');
  });
});
```

```css
/*Chat box*/

#chatbox {
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: table;
  padding: 10px 20px 12px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  height: 40.8em;
  width: 52em;
}


/*Chatbox inside border*/

.chatboxborder {
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px 20px 12px 15px;
  height: 2.8em;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 20em;
}


/*Chat message*/

#chatspace {
  transition-duration: 5s;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  right: 240px;
  left: 20px;
}

#chatbox p {
  transition-duration: 5s;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  background: #E6E6E6;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxtwo">
  <p id="username"></p>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="chatbox">
    <div class="chatboxborder" id="chatboxborder">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fixed" id="boxfive">
  <form name="message">
    <input style="width: 83%" name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" placeholder="Say something">
    <button type="button" id="submitmsg" value="Send">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```